# HTML coding for project

Tags: html

I need to make a website for a project. How can I make a moving gif as a fullscreen background?
[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azrPvB) is what I've done so far (an example)

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>OFFICIAL SQUIDDINC</title>
    <div class="gif-container"></div>
<head>
<html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.gif-container {
  background: url("image.gif") center;
  background-size: cover;

  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. Your question, as written, is unlikely to get an answer here otherwise.

Comment: see if you can jsfiddle or codepen to share what you have

Comment: @SachielParadzik Use the `edit` link underneath your question for updating it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azrPvB This is an example of what I've done

Comment: "make a moving gif" - is it supposed to move around, or animate in place?

Comment: Please use `code snippet` feature of stack overflow instead of providing link to external code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things gone amiss in this snippet.

For the HTML;

You're missing an opening `<html>` tag. Albeit this may just be a bad copy paste for the question.

Your `<title>` is the only thing here that belongs inside the `<head>` tag.

The rest of your html should be encapsulated within a `<body>` tag.

```
<html>  

  <head>
    <title>OFFICIAL SQUIDDINC</title>
  <head>

  <body>
    <div class="gif-container"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

For the CSS;

You don't need to set a height for the `html, body`, however you will need to set it for the gif container. I've gone ahead and used the units `vh and vw`. These mean viewport height and viewport width, respectively. By specifying 100 for each, this will equal exactly the height and width of the browser viewport (screen).

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gif-container {
  background: url("image.gif") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

DEMO;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Byevzv

Comment: Please use `code snippet` feature of stack overflow instead of providing link to external code snippet.